# how can i bring the items (which are green ) to the original status (white color) while uploading local repository to github?

Tags: visual-studio-code

While uploading local repository to github, items in explorer section in visual studio code turned green. How can I bring them to orginal status (white color)? Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Green items in Visual Studio Code represent files that have non-commited modifications to your git repository.

Commit and push the files using VS Code or Terminal and they'll turn white again (until you make other modifications to them)

Comment: Thanks! I have done by deleting folder .git in initialized folder.